# I'm trying to convert a HTML canvas to a HTML image, but I'm getting a blank image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In my application I generate a circle using the HTML element canvas.

The generation of the circle works well: the circle is correctly rendered.

The problem is that I have to put that circle in an option of a select, and as far as I know is not possible to put a canvas inside an option, therefore I probably have to convert the canvas to a base64 image so that I should be able to use it as a background-image of the option.

However, the conversion from canvas to base64 image is not working, as the browser is rendering a blank image.

I have created a fiddle for troubleshooting: https://jsfiddle.net/4hfmp0cs/

Here below you can see the javascript code of the fiddle.

```
function foo()
{
       var circle = getStateCircle("opened");
      //var gl = circle.getContext("webgl", { preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
      var dataUrl = circle.toDataURL("image/png");

      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = dataUrl;
      document.getElementById("container").appendChild(img);
}



function getStateCircle(state)
{
                var stateCircle;

                if(state === "opened")
                {
                    stateCircle = new Circle("#ffcc00", "20px");
                }

                else if(state === "accepted")
                {
                    stateCircle = new Circle("#33cc33", "20px");
                }

                else if (state === "refused")
                {
                    stateCircle = new Circle("#ff3300", "20px");
                }

                else if (state === "closed")
                {
                    stateCircle = new Circle("black", "20px");
                }

                else
                {
                    throw new Error("The state of the offer is unknown");
                }

                stateCircle.buildCircle();
                var circle = stateCircle.getCircle();


                return circle;
}

function Circle(color, size)
{
    this._color = color;
    this._size = size;

    this._circle;

    this.buildCircle = function()
    {
        var style = {
            borderRadius: "50%",
            backgroundColor: this._color,
            height: this._size,
            width: this._size
        }

        this._circle = new ElementBuilder("canvas").withStyleObject(style).getElement();
    }

    this.buildCircleAndAppendTo = function(father)
    {
        this._buildCircle();
        father.appendChild(this._circle);
    }

    this.getCircle = function()
    {
        return this._circle;
    }
}

function ElementBuilder(elementName) {
    var This = this;
    this.element = document.createElement(elementName);

    this.withName = function (name)
    {
        this.element.setAttribute("name", name);
        return this;
    };

    this.withAttribute = function (attributeName, attributeValue)
    {
        this.element.setAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue);
        return this;
    };

    this.withId = function (id)
    {
        this.element.setAttribute("id", id);
        return this;
    }

    this.withClass = function (className)
    {
        this.element.setAttribute("class", className);
        return this;
    }

    this.addClass = function (className)
    {
        this.element.className = this.element.className + " " + className;
        return this;
    }

    this.withTextContent = function (text)
    {
        this.element.textContent = text;
        return this;
    }

    this.withValue = function (value)
    {
        this.element.value = value;
        return this;
    }

    this.getElement = function ()
    {
        return this.element;
    };

    this.withChild = function (child)
    {
        this.element.appendChild(child);
        return this;
    };

    this.withEventListener = function (type, func)
    {
        this.element.addEventListener(type, func);
        return this;
    };

    this.withClickEventListener = function (func)
    {
        this.element.addEventListener("click", func);
        return this;
    }

    this.withDoubleClickEventListener = function (func)
    {
        this.element.addEventListener("dblclick", func);
        return this;
    }

    this.withStyle = function (styleAttribute, value)
    {
        this.element.style[styleAttribute] = value;
        return this;
    }

    this.withStyleObject = function (styleObject)
    {
        ensureIsAnObject(styleObject);

        var keys = Object.keys(styleObject);

        keys.forEach(function (elt) {
            This.withStyle(elt, styleObject[elt]);
        });

        return this;
    }
}



function ensureIsAnObject(value, argumentName) {
    if (!(typeof value == "object")) {
        throw new Error("The argument '" + argumentName + "' should be an object, but it's type is --->" + typeof value);
    }
}
```

The HTML code

```
<div id="container">

</div>

<button onclick="foo()">Append image</button>
```

Comment: And where exactly are you drawing anything on the canvas?

Comment: @Gothdo In the Circle prototype, in the method buildCircle().

Comment: No, you're not drawing anything, you're just applying styles to the canvas element. Learn how canvas works before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere are you actually drawing to the canvas, just styling it with css, which is rendered separate from the canvas. You can replace the canvas with a div, or any other block element and just append that to the document to get the correct effect.

Answer (score -1):

Converts canvas to an image

```
function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return image;
}
```

Or Check in 
http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/vgmFN/